# JS REDUX STORE I want to add an object to an array of objects, which is nest in a specific object in an array

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux

In my app I have a details page, with comments underneath the product. A user has the option to react on a comment with an emoji. Currently my Redux store looks like this:

```
Details: {
ratings: [ {} ],
comments: [ 
{ 
  id: 1,
  comment: 'text',
      reactions: [{
         id: 1,
         emoji: ':)',
         userId: 2
      }, {...}]

}, {...} ]
}
```

When the user choses an emoji to react on a comment, I dispatch an action to the BE, reaction gets saved, responds to FE with newReaction object. I want to add the newReaction object to the array of reactions above for the specific commentId. Below is a shortened version of my reducer:

```
const initialState = {};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case BOOK_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { ...action.payload };

    case REACTION_POST_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        comments: [...state.comments, action.payload],
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I cant figure out how to target the specific commentId object in the comments array. And then add the newReaction object to it.

Answer (score 0):

since state is immutable you need to deep copy it, modify, and return.

perhaps something like:
let nextState = {...state}
nextState.comments = [...state.comments]; //this is critical in order for you to be able to modify the embedded objects/array.

//now modify nextState and update it with your new Obj containing new Emoji

return nextState;

hope this helps! let me know if any of that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Im still rather new to coding so I must admit what you suggested is confusing to me atm. Should I try something like  let nextState = {...state} nextState.comments = [...state.comments]; in the reducer or my actions.js folder?

Comment: no worries, we've all been there :)
yes, you'd be adding this flow in your reducer.  The idea is that since you can't modify state, you have to first copy it, make modifications to the copy, and return that, instead. 
Further to be able to do this we need to copy each stage so if I have an obj within an obj, I have to copy both like how I listed above with your array.

your switch would also slightly change to: 
case REACTION_POST_SUCCESS:{ let nextState = {...state}; //your logic; return nextState; }

let me know if that still raises more questions.